# SharePoint hosted client app part cross domain call

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-rest-api, app, cross-domain

I created SharePoint hosted app which has client app part in it. Added that app part in host web which is trying to get data from another sharepoint application.
I know how cross domain REST call works.[here](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/access-sharepoint-data-from-add-ins-using-the-cross-domain-library)
its giving unuthorized error.

[question also asked here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bd66e25d-f8aa-4fb1-876f-2c5bbf130553/sharepoint-2013-client-web-part-or-app-part-cross-domain-call?forum=appsforsharepoint)

Comment: Does the app have the appropriate permission to the resource you are accessing via the cross domain request?

Comment: How can give permission to app to access data from different site collection from host site? App does have permission on tenant, host site collection and web.

Comment: If you need to read data from a different site collection, then read on tenant will do.  Write permissions for read/write actions.

Comment: I gave full control but its still failing... Giving unauthorized error.

Comment: I am trying to get list data from my site. I don't think giving tenant full control even will cover my site as it's in different web application.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/166300/20615

Comment: This is out of my area of expertise.  I've only developed SharePoint apps for SharePoint Online, and have not had to deal with cross tenant requests.  That answer linked above claims it is not possible and links to some resources that may help you.